Create a new sub-domain in internal DNS server to be a domain alias for another sub-domain
I need to create a new subdomain "abc.example.com" on our internal DNS server running AlmaLinux 9. This subdomain will serve as an alias for "def.example.com," which is another subdomain under the same main domain.
To clarify, "example.com" is the primary domain, with "abc.example.com" and "def.example.com" as its subdomains.
I created the zone file for "abc.example.com" as follows:

$ORIGIN abc.example.com.

$TTL 3H

@          IN SOA NS01.prod.example.com hostmaster.example.com. (

2024042701 ; serial

2H ; refresh

1H ; retry

1W ; expire

3H  ) ; minimum

@ 1D IN NS NS01.prod.example.com.

@ 1D IN NS NS02.prod.example.com.

abc.example.com                        1D IN CNAME def.example.com.


Next, I modified named.conf to include the following configuration for the new subdomain:

zone "abc.example.com" {

type master;
file "/var/named/internals/abc.example.com";
allow-transfer { slave-internal; };


};

I checked named.conf for syntax errors with:

named-checkconf -z

The result indicated no issues. However, when I look up any address within the new subdomain "abc.example.com," the output is: Non-existent domain. Would you please advise how to solve it.

You don’t need and you can’t even use a separate zone file if all you want is  abc.example.com. IN CNAME def.example.com. ; simply include that in the example.com zone - in addition in zone files take when and where you do and don’t add trailing dots . to DNS shorthand records and/or FQDN’s. If and when you want to ensure that something.abc.example.com points to something.def.example.com as well, I think you might want to consider a DNAME record

There is no example.com in my system. I have just some internal sub-domains and external sub-domains.

It works now.
I needed to modify the last line in my zone file for abc.example.com as follows:
abc.example.com.     IN DNAME    def.example.com.
After saving the changes, I restarted the named service. Now, when I use nslookup to look up a name in the abc.example.com domain, the result looks like this:
$ nslookup xxx.abc.example.com
Server:  NS01.def.example.com
Address:  xx.xx.xx.xx
Name:    xxx.def.example.com
Address:  xx.xx.xx.xx
Aliases:  xxx.abc.example.com
This confirms that the DNS changes are working as expected.
